# How did you use that information to help solve/solving the problem?

Tags: meaning, verbs, nouns

I have recently read someone saying:

- > How did you use that information to help solve the problem?

so my question is, what's the grammar rule that makes this right as opposed to

- > How did you use that information to help solving the problem?

Is there a meaning alteration between the two sentences?

Answer (score 2):

Your second sentence is not colloquial.

As it says in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/help-somebody-to-do):

We use help with or without an object:

> Let me help you.
>   Can I help?

We also use help with an object and an **infinitive** with or without *to*:

> *Jack is **helping me to tidy** my CDs*. or *Jack is **helping me tidy** my CDs*.
>
> *Thank you for **helping us find** the right hotel* or *thank you for **helping
>   us to find** the right hotel*.

**Warning:**

We don’t use help with an -ing form:

> I am trying to **help him look** for a new bike.
>   *Not:*
>   I am trying to **help him looking** . . .

So you might say **to help solve** or **to help to solve** but not **to help solving**.

Comment: thanks for the explanation but what's the logic in that rule? why not using the -ing form?

Comment: One might say "How did you use that information to help *in* solving the problem?"

Answer (score 0):

*Help* licenses an infinitival (with or without *to*) as its complement.

The first version is grammatical, but the second, with a gerund-participial as the complement of *help*, is questionable.

In your case, *solve the problem* functions as the complement of *help*.

Comment: This merely echoes @Old Brixtonian's answer, with a change in terminology and a lack of supporting references.